# Using semantic HTML - "nav"

Tags: semantic-ui, nav

I was able to create navigation menus using div.

I now need to create a responsive navigation bar using nav and bootstrap grid. Just a simple navbar with 4 horizontal links centered.

Question: After 12 or so hours searching and reading so many sites, I just cannot find examples of such a basic navigation bar. Is it just that people do not use `<nav>` and always use `<div>` instead?

It is just getting really confusing at this point and I'm feeling stupid as I thought there would be so many examples online. Can anybody clarify please?

Thanks!!

Comment: When you simply replace your `<div>` with `<nav>`, what goes wrong?

Answer (score 1):

**Updated**

I did not see the original need for bootstrap grid. Here is another example that utilizes it and uses markup from the bootstrap official site: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qYjOgv

**HTML**

```
<header>
    <nav class="row">
        <div class="col">col</div>
        <div class="col">col</div>
        <div class="w-100"></div>
        <div class="col">col</div>
        <div class="col">col</div>
      </nav>
</header>
```

**CSS**

```
header {
  background: dodgerblue;
  padding: 30px;
}

.col {
  text-align: center;
}
```

---

**Original**

This is a very simple base that uses flexbox. Pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/odwjMO

**HTML**

```
<header>
  <nav>
    <a>Link 1</a>
    <a>Link 2</a>
    <a>Link 3</a>
    <a>Link 4</a>
  </nav>
</header>
```

**CSS**

```
header {
  background: dodgerblue;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Your basic code & taking out some of my code has me moving again. Keep it simple if something isn't working. I'm good with google but easy to also get lost in all the info. Thanks Staghouse. Hopefully I will be able to help others on here down the line ;-)